# Error in using JQuery with AJAX

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code in index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax check</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" > </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

alert('working...');
$('#ibutton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert('double click');      
$.ajax({
url: "page.html",
cache: false,
success: function(){
$("#message").text('ajax working..');
},
error: function(){
$("#message").text('error in the page');
}
});
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<form action="page.html">
<input type="button" id="ibutton" value="click here"/>
<div id="message"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In `page.html`, the only content is 'working...'
when I click the `click here` button... it shows 'error in the page'... what mistake I have done??

Comment: in IE it works fine but not in chrome

Comment: What is the error, when you click the `click here` button?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.. Can you please `alert` the status code and thrown error in the `error`?

Comment: in IE it shows, `ajax working` but in chrome it shows `error in the page`

Comment: Can you please post the thrown javascript error? in `.error`, write this: `function(req, opt, thrownerror){alert(thrownerror);}`. And post  here the alerted stuff ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `page.html` is in the same folder as the current page. There is not anything wrong with your code. Furthermore, I tested your code in my computer, and it worked like a charm. It seems like the only problem here is the `page.html` is not in the same folder as the currently working script.

Comment: page.html, index.html, jquery-1.8.3.min.js are in same folder.. it is working fine in IE9 ('ajax working' inside #message) but in chrome it shows 'error in the page' inside #message.. is it working in chrome for you?